# Google Apps Script - charts Not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to publish chats data in web apps, Code reference used from "https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/converting-from-uiapp-chart-service-to-html-service-google-visualization-api/"
I am not getting any error in code but not able to view the data in webapp error snap updated below, help me to fix the issue

Please refer the complete script in below link [Script Sheet](https://script.google.com/macros/d/1dRJ3fjYIVRpq0OeIQvEAdSqX3nDkMIFB7i2TcwBZlw66dRfPsUj9nnWq/edit?uiv=2&mid=ACjPJvF9I_xb7z0ApJRFR8TPpv18XNAmE_rFv8txNw4gKvOL2JrD-UEvVChaNGkHywcH7yDHdAdNU6AVoFuPYHuQ5DAc4SFV6flaxIlqbeKMoiv86rPPpz68gk__r11KuYhKqJqIjUr-rM4&splash=yes) 
[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1goPrTBRhS5DjMeojQcpuf91PACDsyo6EDkxmMNtjjJI/edit#gid=0)

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also experienced this and it may be because the Sheet file is set to private.

Steps I've done to fix this:

- I've changed the privacy to with anyone with the link.
- Follow this
  tutorial - [Build a Charts Dashboard with Google Sheets and HTML
  Service](https://ctrlq.org/code/20094-google-charts-dashboard-with-google-sheets).

[image]

### Result:

[image]

### NOTE:

The Google script needs to be published as a Web App and the access should be set to anyone (including anonymous) or you can also limit it to users of your own Google Apps Domain.